# Cannot change height of svg icon in react

Tags: reactjs

I have a Icon component which looks like this:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as Symbol from '../../constants/icons.js';

const Icon = ({ name, viewBox, width, height, transform }) => {
  return (
    <svg
      viewBox={viewBox ? viewBox : '0 0 50 50'}
      width={width}
      height={height}
    >
      <path d={Symbol[name.toUpperCase()].path} transform={transform} />
    </svg>
  );
};

export default Icon;
```

But I have a problem with changing height of Icon if I pass height props like this:

```
 <Icon
                height='100'
                name={'instagram'}
                viewBox="0 0 448 512"
              />
```

Comment: can you try to pass like this ```height={300}``` ?

Comment: @İlker, same problem(

Comment: Seems to work for me. Can you make a codesandbox showing the problem?